# Python Beautiful Soup: Target tag only within another

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been looking for an answer to this question but I'm having little luck. Here is the HTML which I will explain:

```
<div class="news-overflow-hidden">
    <h3>
        <i class="pholder"></i>
        <a href="/news/view/141524/" style="">ЕСПЧ присудил €15 000 экс-главе службы безопасности ЮКОСа</a> </h3>
    <p class="news-text">
        <a href="/news/view/141524/">В такую сумму Европейский суд по правам человека оценил несоблюдение в отношении мужчины презумпции невиновности и нарушение при исследовании свидетельских показаний в судах.</a> </p>
    <i class="news-type-icon"></i>
</div>
```

What I want to do is grab the `<a>`inside of `<p class="news-text">`. The problem is that `<p class="news-text">` exists in other places so if I grab just that, I will grab things I do not need. How can I target `<a>` tags that only exist within this type of paragraph? Could I grab all the paragraphs with this class and then make an if statement for each to see if the contents contain `<a>` or not? Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can apply multiple conditions to multiple elements in a single [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select("p.news-text a")
```

This will locate all `a` elements that are children of the `p` element that has a `news-text` class.

**Demo:**

```
In [11]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [12]: data = """<div class="news-overflow-hidden">
    ...:     <h3>
    ...:         <i class="pholder"></i>
    ...:         <a href="/news/view/141524/" style="">ЕСПЧ присудил €15 000 экс-главе службы безопас
    ...: ности ЮКОСа</a> </h3>
    ...:     <p class="news-text">
    ...:         <a href="/news/view/141524/">В такую сумму Европейский суд по правам человека оценил
    ...:  несоблюдение в отношении мужчины презумпции невиновности и нарушение при исследовании свиде
    ...: тельских показаний в судах.</a> </p>
    ...:     <i class="news-type-icon"></i>
    ...: </div>"""

In [13]: soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

In [14]: for a in soup.select("p.news-text a"):
    ...:     print(a.get_text(strip=True))
    ...:     
В такую сумму Европейский суд по правам человека оценил несоблюдение в отношении мужчины презумпции невиновности и нарушение при исследовании свидетельских показаний в судах.
```